# Program is not able to see file contents

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a code for a high score board, where I read from 2 files and use that info to see if the users score was high enough to get on the board. The main problem is that whenever I try to add the content from a file into an arraylist, the program doesn't see any content in the file, when there is. Here's the code:

```
public static void HighScore() throws IOException { //Method used to check the users score, to see if they are put into the high score board
        FileWriter nameWriter = new FileWriter("highscorenames.txt");
        FileWriter scoreWriter = new FileWriter("highscores.txt");
        PrintWriter printWriter1 = new PrintWriter(nameWriter);
        PrintWriter printWriter2 = new PrintWriter(scoreWriter);
        ArrayList<String> nameList = new ArrayList <String>();
        ArrayList<Integer> scoreList = new ArrayList <Integer>();
        Scanner names = new Scanner(new FileReader ("highscorenames.txt"));
        Scanner scores = new Scanner(new FileReader ("highscores.txt"));
        int temp1;
        String temp2;
        int userScore = 100;
        String userName = "Richard";
        while(names.hasNextLine()) {
            nameList.add(names.nextLine());
        }
        while(scores.hasNextLine()) {
            scoreList.add(Integer.parseInt(scores.nextLine()));
        }
        System.out.println(scoreList.size());
        System.out.println(nameList.size()); 
        
        for(int i = 0; i < scoreList.size(); i++) {
            if(userScore > scoreList.get(i)) {
                temp1 = scoreList.get(i);
                scoreList.set(i,userScore);
                userScore = temp1;
                temp2 = nameList.get(i);
                nameList.set(i,userName);
                userName = temp2;
            }
        }
        printWriter1.print("");
        printWriter2.print("");
        for(int j = 0; j < nameList.size(); j++) {
            printWriter1.println(nameList.get(j));
        }
        for(int k = 0; k < scoreList.size(); k++) {
            printWriter2.println(scoreList.get(k));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you found an answer helpful accept one and upvote

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure if it detects your file, because in some cases you need to add full path to the file with file name even if it is located in the same folder.e.g
your_path_to_file/filename.extension

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like your first line

```
   FileWriter nameWriter = new FileWriter("highscorenames.txt");
```

creates a new file (or at least truncates the old one).  And therefore when you get to

```
   Scanner names = new Scanner(new FileReader ("highscorenames.txt"));
```

there's nothing to read.

If your intent is to read an existing file and then update it, you need to read the old file content first.

Answer (score 0):

Just Set the **append** flag to **true**:

FileWriter nameWriter = new FileWriter("highscorenames.txt", true);

If you write a file which is already exist in the location, It will be overwritten, Unless you set **true** as a second parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Relative paths won't work this way, you get null File references.

For your code to work **as is** you need to place the files to a real path and provide that to FileReader. i.e

> C:\highscores.txt  // for windows

Since you are constructing `ArrayList<String>` objects to store the scores
its better to use the method `Files.readAllLines()` from `java.nio.file.Files` which gives you back a `List<String>` object

or the method `lines()` from `BufferedReader` which gives you a `Stream<String>` object.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class ReadFiles {
        
            public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
                
                List<String> highscores = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("C://highscores.txt"));
                highscores.forEach(System.out::println);
                
                // Relative Path this will be different for ant,maven,gradle etc
                
                InputStream in = ReadFiles.class.getResourceAsStream("highscores.txt");
                Stream<String> highscores_stream = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in)).lines();
                highscores_stream.forEach(System.out::println);
            }
}
```

If you don't use an IDE you can launch from the commandine as of Java 11 for [Single Source files](https://www.baeldung.com/java-single-file-source-code)

[image: Example]